# How can I create a script for 4 multiple dependent drop down menu?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I would like to create a script for this [Sheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1YLckwgSI-HlncQAO04FystvaWE4gbCqpO9JNcrMMOfY/edit?usp=sharing). In Data tab I have all the levels.

With that script I wanna create 4 dependent drop down lists for entire columns with multiple levels in Index tab.

Thanks to this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s-I8Z4nTDak) I could create one script that read one table. But I would prefer avoid create one table with one conditions per row, it would be a table with so many rows.

Expenses include so many sublevels, this is the principal problem.

This is the code:

```js
var mainWsName = "Index";
var leyendaWsName = "Data";
var firstLevelColumn = 2;
var secondLevelColumn = 3;
var thirdLevelColumn = 4;

var ws = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(mainWsName);
var wsData = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(dataWsName);
var data = wsData.getRange(2, 1,wsData.getLastRow(),3).getValues();


function onEdit(e){
  var activeCell = e.range;
  var val = activeCell.getValue();
  var r = activeCell.getRow();
  var c = activeCell.getColumn();
  var wsName = activeCell.getSheet().getName();
  if(wsName === mainWsName && c === firstLevelColumn && r > 1){
    applyFirstLevelValidation(val,r);
  }  else if(wsName === mainWsName && c === secondLevelColumn && r > 1){
    applySecondLevelValidation(val,r);    
  }
  
}  

function applyFirstLevelValidation(val,r){
    if(val === ""){
      ws.getRange(r, secondLevelColumn).clearContent();
      ws.getRange(r, secondLevelColumn).clearDataValidations();
      ws.getRange(r, thirdLevelColumn).clearContent();
      ws.getRange(r, thirdLevelColumn).clearDataValidations(); 
      
    }  else{
      ws.getRange(r, secondLevelColumn).clearContent();
      ws.getRange(r, secondLevelColumn).clearDataValidations();      
      ws.getRange(r, thirdLevelColumn).clearContent();      
      ws.getRange(r, thirdLevelColumn).clearDataValidations(); 
      var filteredData = data.filter(function(l){ return l[0] === val});
      var listToApply = filteredData.map(function(l){ return l[1]}) 
      var cell = ws.getRange(r, secondLevelColumn);
      applyValidationToCell (listToApply,cell);
    }  

} // end onEdit

function applySecondLevelValidation(val,r){
    if(val === ""){
      ws.getRange(r, thirdLevelColumn).clearContent();
      ws.getRange(r, thirdLevelColumn).clearDataValidations();
    }  else{
      ws.getRange(r, thirdLevelColumn).clearContent();
      var firstLevelColValue = ws.getRange(r, firstLevelColumn).getValue();
      var filteredLeyenda = data.filter(function(l){ return l[0] === firstLevelColValue && l[1] === val});
      var listToApply = filteredData.map(function(l){ return l[2]}) 
      var cell = ws.getRange(r, thirdLevelColumn);
      applyValidationToCell (listToApply,cell);
    }  

} // end onEdit

function applyValidationToCell (list,cell){

  var rule = SpreadsheetApp.
  newDataValidation()
  .requireValueInList(list)
  .setAllowInvalid(false)
  .build();
  
  cell.setDataValidation(rule);
  
  
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

**Multilevel Dependent Drop Down Script**

This function uses named ranges to hold the various levels. One could easily extend it by using more named ranges.  The possibilities are large.

The command buttons are checkboxes that trigger functions via an onEdit() function.  There's one button to start another search and there's another button that allows you to select a range to clear the content and the data validations. The clear functionality could probably be made to be a bit more automated after I play with it some more.

You can comment out the e.source.toast() lines in the myOnEdit() function I just left them in there for debugging purposes.

gs:

```
function onOpen() {
  var ui=SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('My Tools')
  .addItem('Create Named Range', 'createNamedRange')            
  .addToUi();
}

function searchInit() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Search');
  var drg=ss.getRangeByName('Departments');
  var rule=SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInRange(drg).build();
  var h=getColumnHeight(3,sh,ss);
  var rg=sh.getRange(h+1,3);
  rg.setDataValidation(rule);
}

function getDropDown(pObj) {
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(pObj));
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Search');
  var prg=ss.getRangeByName(pObj.value);
  if(!prg){
    ss.toast(Utilities.formatString('No additional data for current selection: %s', pObj.value), 'Status', 5);
    return;
  }
  var rule=SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInRange(prg).build();
  var h=getColumnHeight(pObj.col,sh,ss);
  var rg=sh.getRange(pObj.row,pObj.col);
  rg.setDataValidation(rule);
}

function clearRange() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Search');
  var rg=sh.getRange(sh.getActiveRange().getRow(),3,1,sh.getLastColumn()-2);
  rg.clearContent();
  rg.setDataValidation(null);
  rg.deleteCells(SpreadsheetApp.Dimension.ROWS);
}

function launchClearDialog() {
  var html='<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script><link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css"><script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>';
  html+='<style>input{margin:3px 2px 3px 0;}#clrrng{font-size:8px;width:120px;}</style>';
  html+='<input type="text" placeholder="Select Row on the Spreadsheet" id="clrrng" /><label for="clearrang">Range To Clear</label><br />';
  html+='<input type="button" value="Select Row" onClick="getSelectedRange();" /><br />';
  html+='<input type="button" value="Clear Selected Row" onClick="clearSelectedRange();" /><br />';
  html+='<input type="button" value="Exit" onClick="google.script.host.close();" /><br />';
  html+='<script>';
  html+='function clearSelectedRange(){var rg=$("#clrrng").val();google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(){google.script.host.close();}).clearRange(rg);}';
  html+='function getSelectedRange(){google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(rs){$("#clrrng").val(rs);}).getSelectedRange();}';
  html+='</script>';
  var ui=HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html).setWidth(275).setHeight(150);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(ui, "Clear Selected Row");
}

function getSelectedRange() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('search');
  var rg=sh.getRange(sh.getActiveRange().getRow(),3,1,sh.getLastColumn()-2);
  rg.activate();
  return rg.getA1Notation();
}

function clearAll() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Search');
  var rg=sh.getRange(2,3,sh.getLastRow()-1,sh.getLastColumn()-2);
  rg.clear();
  rg.setDataValidation(null);
}

function clearLastRow() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Search');
  var rg=sh.getRange(getColumnHeight(3,sh,ss),3,1,sh.getLastColumn()-2);
  rg.clear();
  rg.setDataValidation(null);
}
```

This is an installable onEdit() function.  Be sure to setup the trigger for it.

```
function onMyEdit(e) {
  e.source.toast('Entry');
  var sh=e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName()!="Search")return;
  e.source.toast('Past Return');
  if(e.range.columnStart==1 && e.range.rowStart==2 && e.value=="TRUE") {
    e.source.toast('searchInit');
    e.range.setValue("FALSE");
    searchInit();
  }
  if(e.range.columnStart==1 && e.range.rowStart==3 && e.value=="TRUE") {
    e.source.toast('Row Clear');
    e.range.setValue("FALSE");
    launchClearDialog();
  }
  if(e.range.columnStart==1 && e.range.rowStart==4 && e.value=="TRUE") {
    e.source.toast('Clear All');
    e.range.setValue("FALSE");
    clearAll();
  }if(e.range.columnStart==1 && e.range.rowStart==5 && e.value=="TRUE") {
    e.source.toast('Clear Last Row');
    e.range.setValue("FALSE");
    clearLastRow();
  }
  if(e.range.columnStart==3 && e.range.rowStart>1 && e.value.length>0) {
    e.source.toast('Category');
    getDropDown({value:e.value,row:e.range.rowStart,col:e.range.columnStart+1});
  }
  if(e.range.columnStart==4 && e.range.rowStart>1 && e.value.length>0) {
    e.source.toast('Products');
    getDropDown({value:e.value,row:e.range.rowStart,col:e.range.columnStart+1});
  }
  if(e.range.columnStart==5 && e.range.rowStart>1 && e.value.length>0) {
    e.source.toast('Types');
    getDropDown({value:e.value,row:e.range.rowStart,col:e.range.columnStart+1});
  }
  if(e.range.columnStart==6 && e.range.rowStart>1 && e.value.length>0) {
    e.source.toast('Quantity');
    getDropDown({value:e.value,row:e.range.rowStart,col:e.range.columnStart+1});
  }
}

function getColumnHeight(col,sh,ss){
  var ss=ss || SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=sh || ss.getActiveSheet();
  var col=col || sh.getActiveCell().getColumn();
  var rg=sh.getRange(1,col,sh.getLastRow(),1);
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  var dvA=rg.getDataValidations();
  Logger.log(vA);
  Logger.log(dvA);
  while(vA[vA.length-1][0].length==0 && !dvA[dvA.length-1][0]){
    vA.splice(vA.length-1,1);
    dvA.splice(dvA.length-1,1);
  }
  return vA.length;
}
```

This function is handy for creating named ranges. You can put the name of the range in one cell and then put all the range values in the cells immediately below it and then select all of them and run the function.

```
function createNamedRange() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sht=ss.getActiveSheet();
  var rng=ss.getActiveRange();
  if(rng.getWidth()==1 && rng.getHeight()>1) {
    var rngA = rng.getValues();
    var name = rngA[0][0];
    var ro = rng.getRow() + 1;
    var co = rng.getColumn();
    var h = rng.getHeight()-1;
    var w = 1;
    var rg = sht.getRange(ro, co, h, 1);
    ss.setNamedRange(name, rg); 
    ss.toast(rg.getA1Notation(),name);
  }
}
```

Here's a screen shot of the Spreadsheet:

[image]

Here's a  video of how it works:(not the current version)

[image]

Search Sheet:

[image]

NamedRanges Sheet:

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much Cooper! It seems perfect. I'm gonna try it asap I can and I tell you. Right now I'm off.

Comment: I've been playing around with it.  You can go as many levels as you want.  I've got four now.  I think I'll be to simplify it down to one or two functions.

Comment: Hi @Cooper, i'm back. Thanks again for your help! I'm trying to understand your code to adapt it to my needs. Sorry to bother you, i'm know i'm a so newbie with this language. To substitute your sheets for mine, I have to substitute where you write "Search" and "Departments", isn't it?

Comment: could you show me your sheets structure? I guess it's the easiest way to understand your code and see how can I manage the different tabs and ranges for myself. That way I won't bother you. Thanks!