# Google Apps Script Data Validations and Dropdown

Tags: excel, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have created a sheet multiple that departments must use.
(Eg.  Dept 1, Dept 2, Dept 3.)
All of these departments have their own content with specific items on the second sheet of the spreadsheet.
(Eg. Dept 1 = A2:F35, Dept 2 = A38:F60, Dept 3 = A63:F89)

A dropdown (Dropdown 1 (*cell H60*)) is used to select the department.

Once a department is selected I need the data validation of the second dropdown(*cell B67*) to change in order to display only the selected department's information. I use multiple V-LOOKUP functions

[image: Sheet Snippet]

I have sat hours trying to create and edit scripts to automatically change the second dropdown data on edit of the first dropdown cell's data, but no luck.

Please let me know if anyone can assist.

[Here is a link to the sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1o8TmoHV3jo9SccQnypmTKZUgC_Tkh_uRGHnBtUBg3NA/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Could you share a copy of the spreadsheet you are working on (free of sensitive information)?

Comment: You can achieve this very quickly with formulas -the only issue is that when you change the value of the selected department in Dropdown 1, the previous inputs in the table below would display red warnings signalling the change in Dropdown 1values. Another thing you seem to have omitted is why department ranges are 2-dimensional (e.g. A2:F35). Are you looking for a single column to populate Dropdown 2? Please share more details about how your project looks like and the desired outcome.

Comment: See if this is what you're looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59495292/7215091

Comment: @AntonDementiev  Thanks and my bad, I have a content sheet consisting of a few columns with named ranges, but only the first column data should be displayed and V-Lookups are used to generate the rest of the rows data, so the range should not be 2D.  Adding a link to sheet now

Comment: @Iamblichus Link added

Comment: I have a doubt regarding this. Do you want a dropdown in each cell in column B? What options would populate each dropdown in column B? For example, should the first dropdown in B have as options `Dep1Item1`, `Dep2Item1` and `Dep3Item1`, and if the dropdown in H is changed to `Dept1`, the dropdown in B is changed to `Dep1Item1`? Is that the case?

Comment: Do you need validation built only for the last row of the range? Do all departments use a single spreadsheet?

Comment: @Iamblichus yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 0):

- You have a dropdown #1 (in this sample, in `H5`) with the names of the different departments.
- You have a series of dropdowns #2 (in column `B`, starting at row 12) with items that belong to one of the departments (the information on which items belong to which departments is contained in sheet `Content`).
- You want to change the items selected in each dropdown #2 when a different option is selected in dropdown #1.

If that's correct, you can use the following [onEdit](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onedite) trigger (check inline comments):

```js
function onEdit(e) {
  var range = e.range;
  var sheet = range.getSheet();
  var column = range.getColumn();
  var row = range.getRow();
  var dropdown1 = range.getValue();
  var options = range.getDataValidation().getCriteriaValues()[0];
  var depts = {}; // Object with key-values like: { departmentName: [itemNames] }
  var currentProp = "";
  if (sheet.getName() === "Main" && column === 8 && row === 5) { // Check that edited cell is dropdown #1
    var contentSheet = e.source.getSheetByName("Content");
    var content = contentSheet.getRange(1, 1, contentSheet.getLastRow()).getValues().map(function(value) {
      return value[0]; // Get departments and items from "Content"
    });
    // Create properties for each department / items in "Content"
    for (var i = 0; i < content.length; i++) {
      if(options.indexOf(content[i]) !== -1) {
        depts[content[i]] = [];
        currentProp = content[i];
      } else {
        depts[currentProp].push(content[i])
      }
    }
    var firstRow = 12;
    var column = 2;
    var numRows = sheet.getLastRow() - firstRow + 1;
    for (var j = 0; j < numRows; j++) { // Iterate through each dropdown #2
      var dropdownRange = sheet.getRange(firstRow + j, column);
      var dropdownValues = dropdownRange.getDataValidation().getCriteriaValues()[0];
      for (var k = 0; k < dropdownValues.length; k++) { // Find element from dropdown that belongs to selected department
        if (depts[dropdown1].indexOf(dropdownValues[k]) !== -1) {
          dropdownRange.setValue(dropdownValues[k]); // Change dropdown value
          break; // End loop
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

#### Note:

- I am assuming the dropdowns are already populated and that the only thing you want to do is to change the selected value from each dropdown #2 when value from dropdown #1 is edited.

Answer (score 0):

I did the following and it works perfectly :

```
    function onEdit(e) {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var cr = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetName();
    var type = sheet1.getRange("L57").getValue(); //GET DROPDOWN VALUE
    var prefix = sheet1.getRange("K57"); //NA
    var suffix = sheet1.getRange("J57"); //NA
    var sheet1 = ss.getSheets()[0];  //get sheet 1

 if(cr == "sheetname"){          //confirm sheet edited
       if((e.range.columnStart==12) && (e.range.rowStart==57)){  //confirm range editied


               if(type == "type I want"){  //DROPDOWN VALUE 
               // ss.toast("this one SELECTED"); //confirmation
                var cell = ss.getRange("B68:B72");  
                cell.setValue("");  //clear all values for no errors when validation changes
                var datarange = sheet4.getRange("A3:A24"); //range info i want as new data validation
                var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInRange(datarange).build();  //get datavalitation
                cell.setDataValidation(rule); //Set data validation
                prefix = "WB";//NA
                sheet1.getRange("K57").setValue(prefix);//NA
               }  //added else if's here for other dropdown values
}
}
```