# Three drop down lists depending on each other

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, drop-down-menu, scripting, dropdown

I need to get three depending drop-down lists, which depend on each other. Here is an editable [sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13nL8a_r7PitNiZkoS570PXhoeg69vCOZEtQ34_TdmOc/edit?usp=sharing) with the example. Cells in the yellow column contain a drop-down list which is based on usual data validation (Options sheet). Cells in the green column give a corresponding drop-down list, which is based on the script. And in blue column I need to get a corresponding list from the sheet Options with names corresponding with the data in the middle green column.

I will appreciate any help.

```
var mainWsName = "master";
var optionsWsName = "options";
var firstLevelColumn = 12;
var secondLevelColumn = 13;
var thirdLevelColumn = 14;

var ws = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(mainWsName);
var wsOptions = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(optionsWsName);


function onEdit(e){
  var activeCell = e.range;
  var val = activeCell.getValue();
  var r = activeCell.getRow();
  var c = activeCell.getColumn();
  var wsName = activeCell.getSheet().getName();
  if(wsName === mainWsName && c === firstLevelColumn && r > 4){
    applyFirstLevelValidation(val,r);
  } else if(wsName === mainWsName && c === secondLevelColumn && r > 4){
    applySecondLevelValidation(val,r);
  } 


} //end onEdit

function applyFirstLevelValidation(val,r){

  if(val === ""){
    ws.getRange(r, secondLevelColumn).clearContent();
    ws.getRange(r, secondLevelColumn).clearDataValidations();
    ws.getRange(r, thirdLevelColumn).clearContent();
    ws.getRange(r, thirdLevelColumn).clearDataValidations();
  } else {
    ws.getRange(r, secondLevelColumn).clearContent();
    ws.getRange(r, secondLevelColumn).clearDataValidations();
    ws.getRange(r, thirdLevelColumn).clearContent();
    ws.getRange(r, thirdLevelColumn).clearDataValidations();
    var filteredOptions = options.filter(function(o){ return o[0] === val });
    var listToApply = filteredOptions.map(function(o){ return o[1] });
    var cell = ws.getRange(r, secondLevelColumn);
    applyValidationToCell(listToApply,cell);
   }

}  



function applySecondLevelValidation(val,r){

  if(val === ""){
    ws.getRange(r, thirdLevelColumn).clearContent();
    ws.getRange(r, thirdLevelColumn).clearDataValidations();
  } else {
    ws.getRange(r, thirdLevelColumn).clearContent();
    var firstLevelColValue = ws.getRange(r, firstLevelColumn).getValue();
    var filteredOptions =options.filter(function(o){ return o[0] === firstLevelColValue && o[1] === val });
    var listToApply = filteredOptions.map(function(o){ return o[2] });
    var cell = ws.getRange(r.thirdLevelColumn);
    applyValidationToCell(listToApply,cell);
   }

}  

function applyValidationToCell(list,cell){

  var rule = SpreadsheetApp
  .newDataValidation()
  .requireValueInlist(list)
  .setAllowInvalid(false)
  .build();

  cell.setDataValidation(rule)
}
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, player. I added the edited script to the sheet, but I still can't get second and third drop down lists...  I just save the changes in onEdit mode. Bu M column doesn't give me a drop down list when I chose a variable in L column.

Comment: Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59495292/7215091

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You want to show the dropdown list to the column "N" by the column "M".

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer? Please think of this as just one of several possible answers.

### Modification points:

- `options` is not declared for the function of `applyFirstLevelValidation` and `applySecondLevelValidation`.
- `r.thirdLevelColumn` of `ws.getRange(r.thirdLevelColumn)` occurs an error. Because `r` is the number.
- `.requireValueInlist(list)` is `.requireValueInList(list)`. It's a spelling mistake.

### Modified script:

When your script is modified, please modify as follows.

#### From:

```
var filteredOptions = options.filter(function(o){ return o[0] === val });
```

#### To:

```
var filteredOptions = wsOptions.getDataRange().getValues().filter(function(o){ return o[0] === val });
```

and

#### From:

```
var filteredOptions =options.filter(function(o){ return o[0] === firstLevelColValue && o[1] === val });
```

#### To:

```
var filteredOptions = wsOptions.getDataRange().getValues().filter(function(o){ return o[0] === firstLevelColValue && o[1] === val });
```

and

#### From:

```
var listToApply = filteredOptions.map(function(o){ return o[2] });
var cell = ws.getRange(r.thirdLevelColumn);
applyValidationToCell(listToApply,cell);
```

#### To:

```
var listToApply = filteredOptions.map(function(o){ return o[2] });
var cell = ws.getRange(r, thirdLevelColumn);  // <--- Modified
applyValidationToCell(listToApply,cell);
```

and

#### From:

```
var rule = SpreadsheetApp
.newDataValidation()
.requireValueInlist(list)
.setAllowInvalid(false)
.build();
```

#### To:

```
var rule = SpreadsheetApp
.newDataValidation()
.requireValueInList(list)  // <--- Modified
.setAllowInvalid(false)
.build();
```

### Whole modified script:

```js
var mainWsName = "master";
var optionsWsName = "options";
var firstLevelColumn = 12;
var secondLevelColumn = 13;
var thirdLevelColumn = 14;

var ws = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(mainWsName);
var wsOptions = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(optionsWsName);

function onEdit(e){
  var activeCell = e.range;
  var val = activeCell.getValue();
  var r = activeCell.getRow();
  var c = activeCell.getColumn();
  var wsName = activeCell.getSheet().getName();
  if(wsName === mainWsName && c === firstLevelColumn && r > 4){
    applyFirstLevelValidation(val,r);
  } else if(wsName === mainWsName && c === secondLevelColumn && r > 4){
    applySecondLevelValidation(val,r);
  } 
} //end onEdit

function applyFirstLevelValidation(val,r){
  if(val === ""){
    ws.getRange(r, secondLevelColumn).clearContent();
    ws.getRange(r, secondLevelColumn).clearDataValidations();
    ws.getRange(r, thirdLevelColumn).clearContent();
    ws.getRange(r, thirdLevelColumn).clearDataValidations();
      } else {
    ws.getRange(r, secondLevelColumn).clearContent();
    ws.getRange(r, secondLevelColumn).clearDataValidations();
    ws.getRange(r, thirdLevelColumn).clearContent();
    ws.getRange(r, thirdLevelColumn).clearDataValidations();
    var filteredOptions = wsOptions.getDataRange().getValues().filter(function(o){ return o[0] === val });  // <--- Modified
    var listToApply = filteredOptions.map(function(o){ return o[1] });
    var cell = ws.getRange(r, secondLevelColumn);
    applyValidationToCell(listToApply,cell);
   }
}  

function applySecondLevelValidation(val,r){
  if(val === ""){
    ws.getRange(r, thirdLevelColumn).clearContent();
    ws.getRange(r, thirdLevelColumn).clearDataValidations();
  } else {
    ws.getRange(r, thirdLevelColumn).clearContent();
    var firstLevelColValue = ws.getRange(r, firstLevelColumn).getValue();
    var filteredOptions = wsOptions.getDataRange().getValues().filter(function(o){ return o[0] === firstLevelColValue && o[1] === val });  // <--- Modified
    var listToApply = filteredOptions.map(function(o){ return o[2] });
    var cell = ws.getRange(r, thirdLevelColumn);  // <--- Modified
    applyValidationToCell(listToApply,cell);
   }
}  

function applyValidationToCell(list,cell){
  var rule = SpreadsheetApp
  .newDataValidation()
  .requireValueInList(list)  // <--- Modified
  .setAllowInvalid(false)
  .build();

  cell.setDataValidation(rule)
}
```

### References:

- [getRange(row, column)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column)
- [requireValueInList(values)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/data-validation-builder#requirevalueinlistvalues)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Comment: Hello Tanaike!! That is exactly what I needed!! Thank you very much for your modifications of the code! It is perfect!

Comment: Hello, Tanaike. The script works perfect, but for the only tab named "master". However now I need to extend the properties of this script)) Is it possible to make it work for several tabs within the same table? Let us say "master", "sheet1", "names". Could you please help me again?  The option **var mainWsName = ["master", "sheet1", "names"];**  does not work:)

Comment: @Sanli Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. I would like to support you. But unfortunately, I cannot understand about your new question. This is due to my poor English skill. I deeply apologize for this. So can you post it as a new question by including the detail information? By this, I would like to correctly understand about your new question and think of the solution. And also, it will help users think of your issue and solution. If you can cooperate to resolve your issue. I'm glad.